# How do you include files from a scala project in eclipse in a java project in netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, netbeans, import

I have a project in java on netbeans 7.3 that I need to add more classes to. However, I am working with scala on eclipse. How can I import those classes from my eclipse project and execute them when I run the program on netbeans?

Not sure since I've never really configured stuff - just coded in prepared environments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a library in your Scala application, i would suggest to use sbt and package the library as a jar and import that jar to your java project.

You will have to define a build file in sbt. I am not sure whether you already defined it and use the sbt package command.

```
 sbt package
```

Try using *[sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html#create-a-project-directory-with-source-code)*

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I'm going to have to recompile my scala and java projects as I develop and make changes to them. Given all the dependencies I have, would I be able to compile them separately and still be able to run everything when I execute from say my Netbeans project? (In other words, would I be able to quickly recompile and launch my whole project or would I have to constantly repackage changes to my scala project and import that jar file to my java project all the time?)